# Getting "Signature expired" error using AWS CLI secretsmanager command on Ubuntu VM

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, aws-secrets-manager

I am trying to retrieve AWS secrets using the secretsmanager CLI command but am getting this error after the command just seems to hang for about 5-6 minutes:

`An error occurred (InvalidSignatureException) when calling the GetSecretValue operation: Signature expired: 20240208T204704Z is now earlier than 20240208T204804Z (20240208T205304Z - 5 min.)`

However, all other AWS CLI commands I have tried work fine on the VM such as `aws sts get-caller-identity` or `aws s3 ls`. I am able to retrieve the secret on my Mac which what the VM is running on and both my VM and Mac have identical `~/.aws/config` and `~/.aws/credentials` files.

I have checked my VMs datetime and it is correct and so is the timezone (`timedatectl` shows what I expect to see), as well as forced a time synchronization using `sudo ntpdate ntp.ubuntu.com`.

I also tried to reinstalled the AWS CLI but no luck (on version 2.15.18)

Any ideas on why this command wont work on my VM?

Comment: Can you please make sure that the VM has Iam role with permissions for AWS secrets added to it?